# jsdom virtual console: TypeError: jsdom.createVirtualConsole is not a function

Tags: jsdom

In:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const initialVirtualConsole = jsdom.createVirtualConsole();
```

I get:

```
TypeError: jsdom.createVirtualConsole is not a function
    at Query.<anonymous> (/my_jsdom_script.js:112:55)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at Query.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/Users/xxx/Sites/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:99:12)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/Users/xxx/Sites/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:144:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/Users/xxx/Sites/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:128:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/xxx/Sites/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (/Users/xxx/Sites/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:73:12)
    at Protocol.write (/Users/xxx/Sites/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/xxx/Sites/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:96:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

I would like to run the tests for jsdom on my local machine to see how jsdom performs in my local environment.

Could anyone be so good as to guide a noob in running the tests in https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/tree/master/test ?

Comment: which version of jsdom do you use?

Comment: jsdom/tree/master ... so a moving target.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's in my `beforeEach()` block (I'm using mocha over node.js to test)

```
    import jsdom from 'jsdom'
    const virtualConsole = jsdom.createVirtualConsole()
    const document = jsdom.jsdom(undefined, {
        virtualConsole: virtualConsole.sendTo(console)
    })
    virtualConsole.on('log', (...args) => {
        // do something with `args` sent to logs
        // e.g, assign result to a variable and run your assertions over it
    })
    window = document.defaultView
    global.window = window
    global.document = document
```

Check out the tests for further examples: https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/master/test/jsdom/virtual-console.js